# Centralizing text on a Surface

Tags: python, pygame

If I have a two surfaces in Pygame, one being a window and another containing some text, how do I programmatically centralize the text surface inside the window (not manually with magic numbers)?

Comment: If you define screen's rect, it is simply: `text.rect.center = screen.rect.center`

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it with math, instead of magic numbers, without even knowing anything about `pygame`:

```
top = outer.get_height()/2 - inner.get_height()/2
left = outer.get_width()/2 - inner.get_width()/2
```

That gives you the top left corner of the inner surface, in the coordinate system of the outer surface, in *any* graphics library (except one whose surfaces' coordinate systems can have different resolutions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and `rect.center`, `rect.topleft`

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect() # get screen rectangle
text_rect = text.get_rect() # get text rectangle
text_rect.center = screen_rect.center # center text on screen
```

now you can blit text on screen in position `text_rect.topleft`

```
screen.blit( text, text_rect.topleft )
```

`rect` has other useful properties:

```
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

---

Full code: (press space to pause)

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600),0,32)

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 72)

        text_pause = font.render("PAUSE", True, (255, 0, 0))

        screen_rect = screen.get_rect() # get screen rect
        text_rect = text_pause.get_rect() # get text rect
        text_rect.center = screen_rect.center # center text on screen

        RUNNING = True
        PAUSED = True

        while RUNNING:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False
                    elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                        PAUSED = not PAUSED

            screen.fill(0)

            if PAUSED:
                screen.blit(text_pause, text_rect.topleft)

            pygame.display.update()

            fpsClock.tick(25)

        # --- finish ---

        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

You can use `rect.center` to center text in mouse position.

Full code: (move mouse)

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600),0,32)

        font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 72)

        text_pause = font.render("PAUSE", True, (255, 0, 0))

        screen_rect = screen.get_rect() # get screen rect
        text_rect = text_pause.get_rect() # get text rect
        text_rect.center = screen_rect.center # center text on screen

        # --- mainloop ---

        RUNNING = True
        PAUSED = True

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False
                    elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                        PAUSED = not PAUSED

                if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                    text_rect.center = event.pos

            # --- calcuations/moves ---

            # --- draws ---

            screen.fill(0)

            if PAUSED:
                screen.blit(text_pause, text_rect.topleft)

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            fpsClock.tick(25)

        # --- finish ---

        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```